# Broken audio after installing Realtek HD drivers

Tags: 12.10, drivers, sound, alsa, realtek

I had some problem with stock audio on the Realtek ALC888S making it a bit too quiet.

So, After reading https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto , I downloaded the HD audio drivers for Kernel 3 and installed them

During the end of the install, sound halted.

I then rebooted my system.

And then, sound does not play anymore.  `oss-test` gives me that `/dev/mixer: No such file or directory`.  Sound settings shows only one Dummy output like this:

[image]

Also,

```
amith@amith-dualcore:~$ ls -l /dev/snd/
total 0
crw-rw---T 1 root audio 116,  1 Feb 17 21:50 seq
crw-rw---T 1 root audio 116, 33 Feb 17 21:50 timer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you linked to says:

> much of the information on this page is outdated

Realtek's page says:

> Audio drivers available for download from the Realtek website ... may not offer the customizations made by your system/motherboard manufacturer.

These warnings are there for a reason.

---

The audio drivers are part of the kernel, so the easiest way to get newer drivers is to [install a newer kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080).